# Can I use Apache Spark for Bluemix In my runtime Node.js program?

Tags: android, node.js, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

You know, as students, we need a final project. Currently, I am creating an Android weather app for my final project.
data source:Insights for Weather
data process engine：Analytics for Apache Spark
Our team's idea is for Android to construct an http request to get data from runtime node.js. Can node.js trigger Apache Spark to process weather data,  return the result to node.js, and finally, have node.js response to Android?
     Who can tell me if this is feasible? we understand everything but how node.js uses the Apache Spark service?
     Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Analytics for Apache Spark on IBM Bluemix can load data from Cloudant for processing. Using Node.js, you can load the weather data for processing into the Cloudant instance connected to your application and the Spark service.

Currently, Spark processing can only be triggered through the interactive notebooks (rather than programmatically). Using a Notebook, you can import that data form Cloudant and run your analysis. This processing results can be exported back into Cloudant.